# Reading two lines from an input file using Scanner

Tags: java

Hi I'm in a programming class over the summer and am required to create a program that reads input from a file. The input file includes DNA sequences ATCGAGG etc and the first line in the file states how many pairs of sequences need to be compared. The rest are pairs of sequences. In class we use the Scanner method to input lines from a file, (I read about bufferedReader but we have not covered it in class so not to familiar with it) but am lost on how to write the code on how to compare two lines from the Scanner method simultaneously.

My attempt:

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException 
{
File inFile = new File ("dna.txt");

Scanner sc = new Scanner (inFile);
while (sc.hasNextLine())
{
  int pairs = sc.nextLine();
  String DNA1 = sc.nextLine();
  String DNA2 = sc.nextLine();
  comparison(DNA1,DNA2);
}
sc.close();
}
```

Where the comparison method would take a pair of sequences and output if they had common any common characters. Also how would I proceed to input the next pair, any insight would be helpful.. Just stumped and google confused me even further. Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Here's the sample input

```
7
atgcatgcatgc
AtgcgAtgc
GGcaAtt
ggcaatt
GcT
gatt
aaaaaGTCAcccctccccc
GTCAaaaaccccgccccc
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
gctagtacACCT
gctattacGcct
```

Comment: `int pairs = sc.nextLine();` this should be `int pairs = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());` Anyhow can you show us the structure of `dna.txt` file for reference.

Comment: But what I understood you have to read the `pairs` outside of `while` loop.

Comment: I thought the while loop just meant that as long as there was another line it would print it, and the first line determines the pairs so I figured it should go into the loop.. Would it still read the first line of the txt outside the loop?

Comment: Yes it will, if there is line available. but once you pass the line  `hasNextLine()` method checks for do the next line available, and if there is it returns `true` keeping the `while` loop running, if not returns `false`. [`See Scanner#hasNextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine())

Comment: When it comes to hasNextLine(), in the while loop, is there a way to store each of the lines as an index of an array and then call them for comparison using my comparison method?

Comment: YOu can make use of String array, but that will be bad as you dont know about the size you will be needing. The better option would be use of [`Class ArrayList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) as it will grow according to your need.

Comment: When it comes to hasNextLine(), in the while loop, is there a way to store each of the lines as an index of an array and then call them for comparison using my comparison method? also, if i put my "int pairs" outside the while loop, would the nextLines after "int pairs"  (in the while loop) start calling line 2,3,4 etc? So I don't need to edit again, my idea for the loop on the amount of lines, say there are 4 pairs so my expression would be for(int i = 0; i < 2*pairs; i++) then in the body i could have a string[] and store each line string[i] and then recall them in my comp. method?

Comment: Yes You can do all the you said, but make sure you check that line is available other wise most probably it will throw `IOException`. Try to implement it and if you caught into any problem then ask the question here. One more thing I am not sure how are you comparing strings but as @Mateusz said, you need to use [String#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) for String comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Smit!

Comment: @user2624368 What will happen if you put million lines in array? Why not use List<>, ok you do not know about lists, check up on lists on google also. That is why you should use scanner if there would be million lines not to read all lines at once.

Answer (score 0):

First why you are doing:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine())
{
  int pairs = sc.nextLine();
```

While you have pairs only in one line not pairs and two lines of input, but number of lines once? Move reading pairs from that while looop and parse it to int, then it does not matter but you could use it to stop reading lines if you know how many lines are there.

Second:

```
throws IOException
```

Might be irrelevant but, really you don't know how to do try catch and let's say skip if you do not care about exceptions?

Comparision, if you read strings then string has method "equals" with which you can compare two strings.

Google will not help you with those problems, you just don't know it all, but if you want to know then search for basic stuff like type in google "string comparision java" and do not think that you can find solution typing "Reading two lines from an input file using Scanner" into google, you have to go step by step and cut problem into smaller pieces, that is the way software devs are doing it.

Ok I have progz that somehow wokrked for me, just finds the lines that have something and then prints them out even if I have part, so it is brute force which is ok for such thing:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class program
{

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException 
{
File inFile = new File ("c:\\dna.txt");

Scanner sc = new Scanner (inFile);
int pairs = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
for (int i = 0; i< pairs-1; i++)
{
    //ok we have 7 pairs so we do not compare everything that is one under another
  String DNA1 = sc.nextLine();
  String DNA2 = sc.nextLine();
  Boolean compareResult = comparison(DNA1,DNA2);

  if (compareResult){
    System.out.println("found the match in:" + DNA1 + " and " + DNA2)  ;
  }
}
sc.close();
}


public static Boolean comparison(String dna1, String dna2){

    Boolean contains = false;
    for (int i = 0; i< dna1.length(); i++)
    {
        if (dna2.contains(dna1.subSequence(0, i)))
        {
            contains = true;
            break;
        }
        if (dna2.contains(dna1.subSequence(dna1.length()-i,dna1.length()-1 )))
        {
            contains = true;
            break;
        }       
    }

    return contains;    
}

}
```

Comment: The equals method won't work because say for instance string one is AGCTATTT and string two is ATCTAGGGG then only sequence they have in common is "CTA" and equals won't catch that. LOL and thats funny because thats exactly what I Googled but I figured I couldn't be the only one asking this. We haven't learned the try catch, only Scanner, Filewriter and Printwriter so far

Comment: I do not know a lot about DNA coding but then you would need to comapre parts of strings and that is another stuff which is searching in dictionary, then you would have to split the line you get in first `nextLine()` and check parts of it with `contains()` method in second string.

Comment: @user2624368 I have updated a little bit my answer with brute force solution which is kinda ok I think.